# How can I write a Java program to draw a box, an oval, and an arrow?

Tags: java

How can I write a Java program to draw a box, an oval, and an arrow?

Comment: In what context? A Swing application?

Answer (score 3):

You'll find what you're looking for in the Java [2D Graphics Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/).  The section on [Drawing Geometric Primitives](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html) shows how to draw rectangles and ovals, and you should be able to put an arrow together after reading the [Drawing Arbitrary Shapes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/geometry/arbitrary.html) section.

Answer (score 3):

I understand it may be hard to start.

So here it goes.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Homework {

     public static void main( String [] args ) {
         JFrame frame = new JFrame();
         frame.add( new JComponent() {
             public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
                // invoke "Graphics" methods here
             }
         });
         frame.setVisible( true );  
     }
}
```

Now, you just have to invoke the methods you need from the [Graphics](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) object and that will take charge of displaying the shapes in the screen:

[sample http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/8784/capturadepantalla201002y.png](http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/8784/capturadepantalla201002y.png)

That would help to start with something useful.

To gain deeper understanding continue with this article: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/). It would help you to understand what's going on.

Finally for "advanced" painting these article is a must read: [2D graphics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/)

Answer (score 2):

System.out.println("■O←");